# require vendor/autoload taking 14 seconds

Tags: php, yii

In our development teams, a decision has been made to not use composer (Not sure why yet). So whenever we want to use a package from 3rd party, we just use composer but copy and paste the files manually into our workspace. So in other words, we never deploy our application using `composer install` or `composer update`. Now I have installed a package called pusher using  `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server`

My issue is that I'm not sure how to use the files since there is no composer autoload. My only solution was to require the autoload `include EXTENSIONS_PATH.'/pusher/vendor/autoload.php';`

However I found that whenever I call the file that includes the autoload, it takes around 14 seconds to load.
We are using php with yii.

Another solution was to use this at the beginning of the application

```
Yii::registerAutoloader(
        function () {
                require_once EXTENSIONS_PATH.'/pusher/vendor/autoload.php';
        }
);
```

Using the above made it work in 200ms, however it conflicted with google API package that was installed in a similar manner and using similar Guzzle dependencies but with versions. If I put that piece of code just before I want to use pusher, the same 14 seconds happens.

Any help is appreciated. This is driving me crazy, and please do not close the question.

Comment: This makes little sense. What's the rational of saying that you shouldn't use composer while you still load the packages individual autoloaders? All you've done now is still using composer while you've removed the main point of it (which is to managing dependencies and versions for you). Loading multiple composer autoloaders are always a bad idea. Either use composer as it's meant to be used, or don't use composer at all.

Comment: The decision was not mine to make. It's the managers before me. Their main concern is that they're worried that deploying with composer might install untested code. It is of course, an unfounded concern, but it requires time to convince them.

Comment: But your current setup doesn't change that in any way, shape or form. You will install _exactly_ the same packages and libraries (since you still need to run composer install per package, or you won't get their dependencies). The only difference is that you've split it up and have lost the dependency management between the different packages. Also, if you update a composer package, you obviously need to test the application after so you should never ship "untested" code anyway.

Comment: You can also still load everything using one composer file like normal but with fixed versions of the packages (so you always get the same versions) and just include the main autoloader. And if you store the lock file and vendor folder in the repo, no one needs to run composer install to use the application after they've cloned it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you well, but I guess you are suggesting that I install all composer packages once and use that vendor folder. The problem is that there are packages that have been installed a long time ago by other developers using composer (google api for one). I may be able to do it, but that requires letting the team and QA's to know that a package that has been installed years ago needs retesting. Anyway, do you know why require_once 'EXTENSION_PATH'./pusher/vendor/autoload.php takes 14 seconds? Maybe if I knw the answer to that I can solve my issue with the current bad setup

Comment: I can't answer why that specific package takes a long time. You need to do some more debugging for that. Are you suggesting that you're using google API code that are _years_ old? Then you probably should update them anyway (seeing that Google change their API's now and again, fixing performance- and security issues etc). You should always try and keep third party libraries as up to date as possible or you might have many security flaws in your code. The way you're doing things now seems a bit backwards. And if you set things up properly, your issue might actually resolve itself.

Comment: _"but that requires letting the team and QA's to know that a package that has been installed years ago needs retesting."_ - Why is that a negative? Your job is to make sure the code is as good as possible and their job is to test things.